# django-vinaigrette - pip install error

Tags: python, django, pip

I'm trying to install this [small app](https://github.com/ecometrica/django-vinaigrette) with pip

```
$ sudo pip install django-vinaigrette
```

I'm getting this error

> Downloading/unpacking django-vinaigrette
>     Downloading django-vinaigrette-0.1.1.tar.gz
>     Running setup.py egg_info for package django-vinaigrette
>       Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "", line 14, in 
>         File "/home/me/my_proj/build/django-vinaigrette/setup.py", line 28, in 
>           long_description = read('README.rst'),
>         File "/home/me/my_proj/django-vinaigrette/setup.py", line 5, in read
>           return open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(**file**), fname)).read()
>       IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/me/my_proj/build/django-vinaigrette/README.rst'
>       Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
>       Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 14, in
>
> File "/home/me/my_proj/build/django-vinaigrette/setup.py", line 28, in
>
> ```
> long_description = read('README.rst'),
> ```
>
> File "/home/me/my_proj/build/django-vinaigrette/setup.py", line 5, in read
>
> ```
> return open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), fname)).read()
> ```
>
> IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/me/my_proj/build/django-vinaigrette/README.rst'

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not doing anything wrong . The problem is that package on pypi does not have the README.rst file required.

Comment: However it seems to be present in the related [github](https://github.com/ecometrica/django-vinaigrette) repository

Comment: Yes , I think you should install from git itself . It seems to have been logged as an issue on the project as well .